# Python split by regex look behind

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to split a string with following code:

```
import re
x = re.split(r"(?<=,)","a,b,c,")
print x
```

The output looks like this:

```
['a,b,c,']
```

What I expected is:

```
['a,','b,','c,']
```

**Update**

I use the solution from Answer: findall

What my need is to split New Line(LF,0x0a)

```
import re
a = '''aaaa
bbbb
cccc
'''
x = re.findall(r"[^%s]+%s" % (0x0a,0x0a),a,re.DOTALL)
print x
```

The result is:

```
[]
```

What expect is there are:

```
['aaaa\n','bbbb\n','cccc\n']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python default `re.split` function won't do splitting on zero width boundaries. So use `re.findall` instead.

```
re.findall(r'\w+,', s)
```

*Update:*

```
>>> a = '''aaaa
bbbb
cccc
'''
>>> re.findall(r".+\n?", a)
['aaaa\n', 'bbbb\n', 'cccc\n']
```

Comment: I think I'd recommend the regex `'[^,]+,'` as this would seem to be closer to the OP's original regex. +1, though.

Comment: @jpmc26 has the better method since his regex will work with a wider range of functions.

Comment: import re
    a = '''aaaaa
    bbbb
    cccc
    '''
    x = re.findall(r"[^%s]+%s" % (0x0a, 0x0a),a,re.DOTALL)
    print x

what for my real need is to split the new line, but this does not work by using findall

Comment: execution the code I got result [], sorry I don't know how to format the code to make it look normal, there are three lines in variable a

Comment: @AvinashRaj Thanks, I accept your answer and put a new question for control codes
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34490684/control-code-in-python-regex