# Control code in Python regex

Tags: python, regex

This is a updated question for 
[Python split by regex look behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34488075/python-split-by-regex-look-behind)

I need to put control codes in regex like 0x0a 0x0d, or any other control codes like 0x07 0x00

When I use the following code, the result is not correct:

```
import re
a = '''aaaaa
bbbb
cccc
'''
x = re.findall(r"[^%s]+%s" % (0x0a,0x0a),a,re.DOTALL)
print x
```

I got `[]`.

I can use the answer in [Python split by regex look behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34488075/python-split-by-regex-look-behind) as the control code are `0x0a==\n`, what about other control codes?

Comment: `"[^%s]+%s" % (0x0a,0x0a)` == `'[^10]+10'`. So actually you're using `x = re.findall(r'[^10]+10', a, re.DOTALL)` instead of `x = re.findall(r'[^\n]+\n', a, re.DOTALL)`.

Comment: @KevinGuan Thanks, I got the answer now

Comment: Then post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Reminded by @KevinGuan, I found out the problem

Here is the correct code:

```
import re
a = '''aaaaa
bbbb
cccc
'''
x = re.findall(r"[^%s]+%s" % (chr(0x0a),chr(0x0a)),a,re.DOTALL)
print x
```

I'm also a Perler, in Perl we can write like this:

```
$Line =~ s/,[\t ]*(\x0d?\x0a)/,$1/g;
```

When I porting Perl script Python, I did not realize the difference